# Is array of strings key accepts object in mongodb with nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I had this schema where I am expecting array of strings in labels .But when I pass a array of objects its taking "**_id**" from that object as a string. Here is a schema  **enq.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var enquirySchema = new Schema({
mobile:{type:String,required:true},
email:{type:String,required:false,default:null},
createdOn : {type:String,default:null},
gender:{type:String,required:false,default:null},
labels:[String]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Enquiry',enquirySchema);
```

I am just requesting api with this data

```
{
"enquiries": [{
    "dateofenquiry": "1533039060000", 
    "labels": [
              {"name": "Lost", "colourCode":" #82E0AA", "_id": 
                    "5b3602ee634aa100012953f5", "type": "Default"}
    ],
    }]
}
```

Even I am sending objects in array it is taking _id as its string. Here is a snap of this record in db.

[image]

I just want to know the reason why it was happening I didn't find anything about this in google. Please help me to understand this issue. How can I overcome this ?

Comment: hmm, when you define `labels:[String]` how you expect it to hold anything but strings?

Comment: What do you mean ? I didn't get ur point

Comment: *I had this schema where **I am expecting array of strings** in labels*. If I get it right, you get array of strings there which seems to meet your expectations. Is it a problem?

Comment: My problem is to know is this happens when we pass array of objects and it takes _id from it?

Comment: you are passing an array of objects to labels which is part of a schema that says labels is an array of strings. It is surprisingly does not throws an error. I assume that the default projection of object to string in mongoose is to use the _id. You should pass data such as: 
`{
"enquiries": [{
    "dateofenquiry": "1533039060000", 
    "labels": ["Lost"]
}`

Comment: @dimagolovin, why "surprisingly"? It casts objects to strings as defined in schema. Syed, doesn't screenshot prove it indeed happens? If you are wondering why it uses _id: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/3b345be86763b6c8580e5a3748b046b42b5e4227/lib/cast/string.js#L23